# Getting this error after having Windows reinstalled on device: TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I just had my device repaired and Windows was reinstalled. A whole bunch of apps and programs were deleted from my device in the process including VSCode and Node.js. I used to have node-v19.4.0-x64, but I just downloaded node-v21.6.2-x64, latest version. Ever since then I have been unable to use and npm commands in VSCode. No matter which project I'm in or which command I use, this error shows up:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\es6\validate-engines.js:31
    throw err
    ^

TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fs-minipass\lib\index.js:136:4)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1378:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1437:10)      
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1212:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1237:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\cacache\lib\content\read.js:4:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1378:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1437:10)
```

I already tried uninstalling and reinstalling node multiple times. I also tried installing the LTS version of node.